# How can i get angles based on a GameObject's posistion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting from a sensor 4 parameters every frame, O (origin), W (UP), V(FORWARD) and U(RIGHT), they are Vector3 elements, with this values i can know the position of my object is in space, but i can't find out the rotation to represent all movemets that the object does.

this is what i get so far(this run every frame with new values for entry vector):

```
Vector3 vetO = new Vector3(entry[0], entry[4], entry[8]); //o
Vector3 vetU = new Vector3(entry[1], entry[5], entry[9]); //u
Vector3 vetV = new Vector3(entry[2], entry[6], entry[10]); //v
Vector3 vetW = new Vector3(entry[3], entry[7], entry[11]); //w

//Here i'm doing this to analize the rotation of a plan
vetW.x = 0;
vetU.z = 0;
vetV.y = 0;

float angleX = Vector3.Angle(vetW, Vector3.up);
float angleY = Vector3.Angle(vetV, Vector3.forward);
float angleZ = Vector3.Angle(vetU, Vector3.right);

//This is because unity bug, when angle is up to 180º
angleX = vetW.z < 0 ? -angleX : angleX;
angleY = vetV.x < 0 ? -angleY : angleY;
angleZ = vetU.y < 0 ? -angleZ : angleZ;

Vector3 angles  = new Vector3(angleX, angleY, angleZ);
transform.eulerAngles = angles;
transform.localPosition = vetO;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the rotation of a certain gameobject, right?

To do this, you can use `YourGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles` to give you a rotation in the form of Vector3. If you wanted to get just one angle you can use `YourGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x`,`YourGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y` or `YourGameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z`

Comment: actually i have a series of space position and i want to extract the angles between one position and another.

Comment: So you want to get the angle in between 2 objects? (sorry, but I don't really understand what you want)